# Trying to loop over the object and find the key with max value - getting inaccurate answer

Tags: javascript, loops, object, max

Trying to find max value in values but keep getting inaccurate value. What have I done wrong?

```
  const findBestEmployee = function(employees) {
  let theBest = Object.values(employees)[0];
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(employees)) {
    if (value > theBest){
      theBest = value
    }
    return key
}
};



console.log(
  findBestEmployee({
    ann: 29,
    david: 35,
    helen: 1,
    lorence: 99,
  })
);
```

Output is `ann` istead of `lorence` - what i did wrong?

Comment: After the very first comparison, your code returns the key and thus exits the function. You need to also store the key in a variable instead when `value > theBest`, then return that found key at the end.

Comment: max value or the key of the max value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to maintain the key too and then return the best key after the loop. You are returning it on the first run of the loop by putting it inside the loop.

```
const findBestEmployee = function(employees) {
  let theBest = Object.values(employees)[0];
  let theBestKey = Object.keys(employees)[0];
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(employees)) {
    if (value > theBest){
      theBest = value;
      theBestkey = key;
    }

  }
  return theBestkey;
};
```

Comment: If it resolved the issue then you can accept the answer too. Thanks

Comment: Please explain, why do we need to set a variable for these?

Comment: To maintain the best key, value pair based on the requirement. Its your requirement to get the key of the best employee therefore. There can be other solutions to the same problem too. But here the answer was only to point out whats wrong in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the value inside the `for` loop, therefore the first item is always returned as the `bestEmployee`.

```js
const findBestEmployee = function(employees) {
  let bestPerformance = Object.values(employees)[0];
  let bestEmployeeName = Object.values(employees)[1];
  for (let [name, performance] of Object.entries(employees)) {
    if (performance > bestPerformance) {
      bestPerformance = performance;
      bestEmployeeName = name;
    }
  }
  return bestEmployeeName;
};

console.log(
  findBestEmployee({
    ann: 29,
    david: 35,
    helen: 1,
    lorence: 99,
  }),
);
// lorence
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another way around, based on `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
const employees = {ann:29,david:35,helen:1,lorence:99},

      getKeyOfMax = obj => 
        Object
          .keys(obj)
          .reduce((r,key) => 
            obj[key]>obj[r] ? key : r)
            
console.log(getKeyOfMax(employees))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```